# Method Calling with Time of 2 Seconds

Tags: c#

I want to call below 2 methods with the time difference of 2 seconds and these should be called continuously one after one, these methods will change the label text, how can I do it

This is what I have tried for timer :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ //timer interval is set to 2000 
  //also is enabled 
  method1(); 
  method2(); 
 } 
public void method1() 
{ 
  label1.Text = "method1 called"; 
 } 
 public void method2() 
 { 
    label1.Text = "method2 called"; 
 }
```

Comment: You could do it with a timer.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: i tried but it stuck on method 2

Comment: Then show what you have tried and we might be able to help you figure out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: And learn how to format your questions please, this one is a mess.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //timer interval is set to 2000
            //also is enabled
            method1();
          
            method2();


        }

      

       public void method1()
        {

            label1.Text = "method1 called";
        }

        public void method2()
        {

            label1.Text = "method2 called";
           
        }

Comment: If you're doing this with a user interface program, you probably *don't* want to call the next function in the same listener; anytime a program freezes up and stops responding (won't let you move it, no UI effects work) this is what's happening. You'll likely want to find a way to set up a future timed event, such that you can still respond to other event listeners.

Comment: Not in the comments, edit the question please!

Comment: Do you want `method2` to be called 2 seconds after `method1` is called, or 2 seconds after `method1` returns? Or do you want to call `method1`, then `method2` immediately after, then wait 2 seconds and call them again? What, exactly, do you want to happen?

Comment: @Jite edited, please check, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JimMischel sorry i make it confuse, actually i want to call method 1 for 2 seconds, after 2 seconds method2 and this method2 will stay for 2 seconds and so on again method 1 will called for 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response in comments, I think you want your timer event handler to be something like this:

```
// Declared at class scope
private int whichMethod = 1;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (whichMethod == 1)
    {
        method1();
        whichMethod = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        method2();
        whichMethod = 1;
    }
}
```

That just alternates which method is called at each tick, which should fill the requirements that you stated in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Thread.Sleep on the main tread as you'd got blocked main UI thread.
Use asynch approach provided by TPL for waiting operations, for example:

Use Task.Delay for waiting:

```
method1();
Task task = Task.Delay(2000)
            .ContinueWith(t => method2());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a Thread.Sleep(2000) out of the question as a solution? It will be slightly innacurate, but probably good enough for most purposes.

```
while(true){ //This will never stop
    method1();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    method2();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```